# How to display a date in moments ago format

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor, momentjs

I have binded a date to an  tag using razor, in the following way.

```
<h4>@updates.UpdatedDate</h4>
```

This would display the date in the following manner:

> 10/1/2016 8:30:02 AM

However, I would need the date to be displayed as

> 12 days ago

Moments ago format. And i know we can use moment.js for this. But do i call the javascript function on the value

Comment: You're going to have to use javascript to get your value with momentJS then use something like .html() and set that <h4> tag to the javascript variable. You're not going to be able to use razor directly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few ways you could do this in the MVC way (server-side), instead of attempting to call a JavaScript function (client-side):

**Option 1:**
Adding a property to your model/view model that does the conversion for you:

```
public HtmlString MomentDate
{
    get
    {
        string convertedDate = // Write your UpdatedDate conversion logic here.
        return new HtmlString(convertedDate);
    }
}
```

**Option 2** Write a custom HtmlHelper extension

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static HtmlString MomentDateFormat(this HtmlHelper helper, DateTime value)
    {
        string convertedDate = // Write your UpdatedDate conversion logic here.
        return new HtmlString(convertedDate);
    }
}
```

And then calling it in your razor view:

```
<h4>@Html.MomentDateFormat(updates.UpdatedDate)</h4>
```

I would generally go with option 2, but I'm going to get into the semantics of why.